# C++ : Red-Black Tree with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, tree

This is my C++ implementation of a Red-Black Tree, referring the CLRS book.
Half for fun, half for studying.

- As implementing child node, I chose `std::unique_ptr` over `std::shared_ptr` because `std::unique_ptr` is cheaper/faster and the nodes are not shared across multiple threads with indeterminate access order. Of course, this decision made the implementation extremely annoying.
- To test it, I inserted and deleted integers from 1 to 100000 with random order. Comparing with `std::set` (which uses raw pointers), the benchmark gives:

```
Inserting 100000 elements:
unique ptr red-black tree : 40 ms
standard red-black tree : 35 ms
Deleting 100000 elements:
unique ptr red-black tree : 49 ms
standard red-black tree : 45 ms
```

Features could be useful but not been implemented:

- Iterators.
- Join operation.

Any feedback will be welcomed, thanks!

````
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <chrono>

std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());

enum class Color {
    Red,
    Black
};

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T key;
    Color color;
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> right;
    Node<T>* parent;

    Node(const T& key) : key {key}, color {Color::Red}, parent {nullptr} {}
};

template <typename T>
struct RBTree {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> root;

private:
    void LeftRotate(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>&& x) {
        auto y = std::move(x->right);
        x->right = std::move(y->left);
        if (x->right) {
            x->right->parent = x.get();
        }
        y->parent = x->parent;
        auto xp = x->parent;
        if (!xp) {
            auto px = x.release();
            root = std::move(y);
            root->left = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(px);
            root->left->parent = root.get();
        } else if (x == xp->left) {
            auto px = x.release();
            xp->left = std::move(y);
            xp->left->left = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(px);
            xp->left->left->parent = xp->left.get();
        } else {
            auto px = x.release();
            xp->right = std::move(y);
            xp->right->left = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(px);
            xp->right->left->parent = xp->right.get();
        }
    }

    void RightRotate(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>&& x) {
        auto y = std::move(x->left);
        x->left = std::move(y->right);
        if (x->left) {
            x->left->parent = x.get();
        }
        y->parent = x->parent;
        auto xp = x->parent;
        if (!xp) {
            auto px = x.release();
            root = std::move(y);
            root->right = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(px);
            root->right->parent = root.get();
        } else if (x == xp->left) {
            auto px = x.release();
            xp->left = std::move(y);
            xp->left->right = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(px);
            xp->left->right->parent = xp->left.get();
        } else {
            auto px = x.release();
            xp->right = std::move(y);
            xp->right->right = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(px);
            xp->right->right->parent = xp->right.get();
        }
    }

public:
    Node<T>* Search(const T& key) {
        return Search(root.get(), key);
    }

    void Insert(const T& key) {
        auto z = std::make_unique<Node<T>>(key);
        Insert(std::move(z));
    }

    void Delete(const T& key) {
        auto z = Search(key);
        Delete(z);
    }

private:
    Node<T>* Search(Node<T>* x, const T& key) {
        if (!x || x->key == key) {
            return x;
        }
        if (key < x->key) {
            return Search(x->left.get(), key);
        } else {
            return Search(x->right.get(), key);
        }
    }

    void Insert(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> z) {
        Node<T>* y = nullptr;
        Node<T>* x = root.get();
        while (x) {
            y = x;
            if (z->key < x->key) {
                x = x->left.get();
            } else {
                x = x->right.get();
            }
        }
        z->parent = y;
        if (!y) {
            root = std::move(z);
            InsertFixup(std::move(root));
        } else if (z->key < y->key) {
            y->left = std::move(z);
            InsertFixup(std::move(y->left));
        } else {
            y->right = std::move(z);
            InsertFixup(std::move(y->right));
        }
    }

    void InsertFixup(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>&& z) {
        auto zp = z->parent;
        while (zp && zp->color == Color::Red) {
            auto zpp = zp->parent;
            if (zp == zpp->left.get()) {
                auto y = zpp->right.get();
                if (y && y->color == Color::Red) {
                    zp->color = Color::Black;
                    y->color = Color::Black;
                    zpp->color = Color::Red;
                    zp = zpp->parent;
                } else {
                    if (z == zp->right) {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(zpp->left));
                        zp = zpp->left.get();
                    }
                    zp->color = Color::Black;
                    zpp->color = Color::Red;
                    auto zppp = zpp->parent;
                    if (!zppp) {
                        RightRotate(std::move(root));
                    } else if (zpp == zppp->left.get()) {
                        RightRotate(std::move(zppp->left));
                    } else {
                        RightRotate(std::move(zppp->right));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                auto y = zpp->left.get();
                if (y && y->color == Color::Red) {
                    zp->color = Color::Black;
                    y->color = Color::Black;
                    zpp->color = Color::Red;
                    zp = zpp->parent;
                } else {
                    if (z == zp->left) {
                        RightRotate(std::move(zpp->right));
                        zp = zpp->right.get();
                    }
                    zp->color = Color::Black;
                    zpp->color = Color::Red;
                    auto zppp = zpp->parent;
                    if (!zppp) {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(root));
                    } else if (zpp == zppp->left.get()) {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(zppp->left));
                    } else {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(zppp->right));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        root->color = Color::Black;
    }

    Node<T>* Transplant(Node<T>* u, std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>&& v) {
        if (v) {
            v->parent = u->parent;
        }
        Node<T>* w = nullptr;
        if (!u->parent) {
            w = root.release();
            root = std::move(v);
        } else if (u == u->parent->left.get()) {
            w = u->parent->left.release();
            u->parent->left = std::move(v);
        } else {
            w = u->parent->right.release();
            u->parent->right = std::move(v);
        }
        return w;
    }

    Node<T>* Minimum(Node<T>* x) {
        if (!x) {
            return x;
        }
        while (x->left) {
            x = x->left.get();
        }
        return x;
    }

    void Delete(Node<T>* z) {
        if (!z) {
            return;
        }
        Color orig_color = z->color;
        Node<T>* x = nullptr;
        Node<T>* xp = nullptr;
        if (!z->left) {
            x = z->right.get();
            xp = z->parent;
            auto pz = Transplant(z, std::move(z->right));
            auto upz = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(pz);
        } else if (!z->right) {
            x = z->left.get();
            xp = z->parent;
            auto pz = Transplant(z, std::move(z->left));
            auto upz = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(pz);
        } else {
            auto y = Minimum(z->right.get());
            orig_color = y->color;
            x = y->right.get();
            xp = y;
            if (y->parent == z) {
                if (x) {
                    x->parent = y;
                }
                auto pz = Transplant(z, std::move(z->right));
                y->left = std::move(pz->left);
                y->left->parent = y;
                y->color = pz->color;
                auto upz = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(pz);
            } else {
                xp = y->parent;
                auto py = Transplant(y, std::move(y->right));
                py->right = std::move(z->right);
                py->right->parent = py;
                auto upy = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(py);
                auto pz = Transplant(z, std::move(upy));
                py->left = std::move(pz->left);
                py->left->parent = py;
                py->color = pz->color;
                auto upz = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(pz);
            }
        }
        if (orig_color == Color::Black) {
            DeleteFixup(x, xp);
        }
    }

    void DeleteFixup(Node<T>* x, Node<T>* xp) {
        while (x != root.get() && (!x || x->color == Color::Black)) {
            if (x == xp->left.get()) {
                Node<T>* w = xp->right.get();
                if (w && w->color == Color::Red) {
                    w->color = Color::Black;
                    xp->color = Color::Red;
                    auto xpp = xp->parent;
                    if (!xpp) {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(root));
                    } else if (xp == xpp->left.get()) {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(xpp->left));
                    } else {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(xpp->right));
                    }
                    w = xp->right.get();
                }
                if (w && (!w->left || w->left->color == Color::Black)
                    && (!w->right || w->right->color == Color::Black)) {
                    w->color = Color::Red;
                    x = xp;
                    xp = xp->parent;
                } else if (w) {
                    if (!w->right || w->right->color == Color::Black) {
                        w->left->color = Color::Black;
                        w->color = Color::Red;
                        auto wp = w->parent;
                        if (!wp) {
                            RightRotate(std::move(root));
                        } else if (w == wp->left.get()) {
                            RightRotate(std::move(wp->left));
                        } else {
                            RightRotate(std::move(wp->right));
                        }
                        w = xp->right.get();
                    }
                    w->color = xp->color;
                    xp->color = Color::Black;
                    w->right->color = Color::Black;
                    auto xpp = xp->parent;
                    if (!xpp) {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(root));
                    } else if (xp == xpp->left.get()) {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(xpp->left));
                    } else {
                        LeftRotate(std::move(xpp->right));
                    }
                    x = root.get();
                } else {
                    x = root.get();
                }
            } else {
                Node<T>* w = xp->left.get();
                if (w && w->color == Color::Red) {
                    w->color = Color::Black;
                    xp->color = Color::Red;
                    auto xpp = xp->parent;
                    if (!xpp) {
                        RightRotate(std::move(root));
                    } else if (xp == xpp->left.get()) {
                        RightRotate(std::move(xpp->left));
                    } else {
                        RightRotate(std::move(xpp->right));
                    }
                    w = xp->left.get();
                }
                if (w && (!w->left || w->left->color == Color::Black)
                    && (!w->right || w->right->color == Color::Black)) {
                    w->color = Color::Red;
                    x = xp;
                    xp = xp->parent;
                } else if (w) {
                    if (!w->left || w->left->color == Color::Black) {
                        w->right->color = Color::Black;
                        w->color = Color::Red;
                        auto wp = w->parent;
                        if (!wp) {
                            LeftRotate(std::move(root));
                        } else if (w == wp->left.get()) {
                            LeftRotate(std::move(wp->left));
                        } else {
                            LeftRotate(std::move(wp->right));
                        }
                        w = xp->left.get();
                    }
                    w->color = xp->color;
                    xp->color = Color::Black;
                    w->left->color = Color::Black;
                    auto xpp = xp->parent;
                    if (!xpp) {
                        RightRotate(std::move(root));
                    } else if (xp == xpp->left.get()) {
                        RightRotate(std::move(xpp->left));
                    } else {
                        RightRotate(std::move(xpp->right));
                    }
                    x = root.get();
                } else {
                    x = root.get();
                }
            }
        }
        if (x) {
            x->color = Color::Black;
        }
    }

};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node<T>* node) {
    if (node) {
        os << node->left.get();
        os << node->key;
        if (node->color == Color::Black) {
            os << "● ";
        } else {
            os << "○ ";
        }
        os << node->right.get();
    }
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const RBTree<T>& tree) {
    os << tree.root.get();
    return os;
}

int main() {
    constexpr size_t SIZE = 100'000;
    std::vector<int> v (SIZE);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), gen);
    RBTree<int> rbtree;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto n : v) {
        rbtree.Insert(n);
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dt1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);

    std::set<int> rbset;
    t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto n : v) {
        rbset.insert(n);
    }
    t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dt2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);

    std::cout << "Inserting " << SIZE << " elements:\n";
    std::cout << "unique ptr red-black tree : " << dt1.count() << " ms\n";
    std::cout << "standard red-black tree : " << dt2.count() << " ms\n";

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), gen);

    t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto n : v) {
        rbtree.Delete(n);
    }
    t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dt3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);

    t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto n : v) {
        rbset.erase(n);
    }
    t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dt4 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);

    std::cout << "Deleting " << SIZE << " elements:\n";
    std::cout << "unique ptr red-black tree : " << dt3.count() << " ms\n";
    std::cout << "standard red-black tree : " << dt4.count() << " ms\n";

}
```
````

Comment: I am confused about usage of `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>&& z`. Normally one either passes a raw pointer or unique_ptr depending on whether you pass ownership over the object or not. Passing rvalue-reference of unique_ptr makes little to no sence. I can understand lvalue reference of unique_ptr - for relocating stuff. But rvalue reference? Just why?

Comment: @ALX23z No, lvalue referenced ```std::unique_ptr``` parameter cannot transfer its ownership in the scope.

Comment: Look for internet guides on these things before giving someone an advice, please. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114913/7772722

Comment: Quote from the reply in the SO link above: ...Although your argument favoring passing by value over passing by rvalue reference makes sense, I think that the standard itself always passes unique_ptr values by rvalue reference (for instance when transforming them into shared_ptr). The rationale for that might be that it is slightly more efficient (no moving to temporary pointers is done) while it gives the exact same rights to the caller (may pass rvalues, or lvalues wrapped in std::move, but not naked lvalues)....

Comment: In that question was referred an odd case of instantiating base from `unique_ptr` to base. I doubt that standart passes unique_ptr by rvalue reference unless it is done with a generic scope - and they might be doing it due to complexity of possible non-trivial deleter.

Comment: In your case you have a function with quite a lot of code. It won't be inlined. And since you pass unique_ptr by reference it will have to dereference it almost each it is being accessed. This is because it might coincide with other unique_ptr inside the function.

Comment: Another problem is that by the end of the function - it might not have moved at all. It is a good way to confuse user that assumes that the object gets moved and he has an empty unique_ptr. As well you should note that in the answer they told him that it is best to accept as an instance and not a reference.

Comment: Hi @frozenca thank you for taking part in the review queues, but please be careful when using the _No Action Needed_ action in the _First Posts_ queue. For more information please read [First Post Review Queue — what is it? Why is it a bad idea to click “No Action Needed”?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1946). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## Don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`

You have to `#include <algorithm>` to get `std::shuffle`.

## Move `struct Node` and `enum class Color` inside `struct RBTree`

A `Node` is just an implementation detail of `RBTree`. It is better to move it inside `struct RBTree`. This also ensures you can just write `Node` instead of `Node<T>` everywhere. The same goes for `Color`. In fact, `Color` is just a property of a `Node`, so it could be moved into `struct Node`, but in this case it would just involve unnecessary typing.

This is how it looks:

```
template <typename T>
struct RBTree {
    enum class Color {
       Red,
       Black,
    };

    struct Node {
        T key;
        Color color;
        std::unqiue_ptr<Node> left;
        ...
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;

private:
    ...
};
```

There is a slight difficulty changing the `operator<<` overload for `Node`, because `Node` is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) of `RBTree<T>`. To make it compile, you have to add `typename` before `RBTree<T>::Node`:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, typename RBTree<T>::Node *node) {
    ...
}
```

## The public `Search()` function should not return a `Node *`

`Node`s are just an implementation detail of your tree. By exposing this, it allows a user of your tree to make modifications to a `Node` that could cause the tree to become corrupted. I would make it return the key found in the tree as a `const T*` instead:

```
const T* Search(const T& key) {
    auto z = Search(root.get(), key);
    return z ? &z->key : nullptr;
}
```

Another option is to return the key by value, and use `std::optional<T>` so you can inform the caller that the key was not in the tree:

```
std::optional<T> Search(const T& key) {
    auto z = Search(root.get(), key);
    return z ? std::make_optional(z->key) : nullopt;
}
```

You have to modify `Delete()` slightly to compensate for this.

## Make functions that do not modify the tree `const`

Make functions that do not change the tree `const`, so the compiler can generate better code, and will also allow you to call those functions on a `const RBTree`. The functions relating to searches can all be marked `const`:

```
const T* Search(const T& key) const { ... }
Node* Search(Node* x, const T& key) const { ... }
Node* Minimum(Node* x) const { ... }
```

## Some unnecessary code

I see some lines of code that basically do nothing and could be simplified. For example, in `Delete()`:

```
auto pz = Transplant(z, std::move(z->right));
auto upz = std::unique_ptr<Node>(pz);
```

And afterwards, `upz` is no longer used. The above can be simplified to:

```
delete Transplant(z, std::move(z->right));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The purpose of ```upz``` is to free pointer ```pz```.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add the `delete` there. Moving something into a temporary `unique_ptr<>` to free it is a very roundabout way :) If you don't like the raw `delete`, then consider having `Transplant()` return a `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead.